# Bad performance for parallel N-Body in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I wrote an N-body implementation in Haskell and tried to parallelize the updating of position of the particles (outer loop) using parList. However, the performance improvement from 1 to 3 cores is small, and it actually becomes worse for 4 cores. Here is the code, using 5 particles:

```
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra
import Data.List (zipWith4)
import Data.List.Split
import Control.DeepSeq
import System.Environment
import Control.Parallel.Strategies


type Vec = Vector Double

data Particle = Particle
    { tag      :: Int
    , position :: !Vec
    , velocity :: !Vec
    , mass     :: Double
    }

instance Eq Particle where
  p1 == p2 = (tag p1) == (tag p2)

instance Show Particle where
  show p = show $ position p

instance NFData Particle where
  rnf p = t `seq` ps `seq` vel `seq` m `seq` ()
    where
        t   = tag p
        ps  = position p
        vel = velocity p
        m   = mass p

data System = System
    { number :: Int
    , particles :: [Particle]
    }

instance Show System where
    show sys = show (particles sys)

instance NFData System where
    rnf sys = rnf $ particles sys


g :: Double
g = 6.674e-11

-- | Construct a vector from a list of elements
mkVector :: [Double] -> Vec
mkVector = vector

-- | Construct a system from a given list of
-- position vectors, velocity vectors, and masses
mkSystem :: [(Vec, Vec, Double)] -> System
mkSystem xs = System
    { number = length xs
    , particles = map (apply Particle) $ zipWith cons [0..] xs
    }
    where
    cons y (a, b, c)     = (y, a, b, c)
    apply f (y, a, b, c) = f y a b c


-- | Calculate the gravitational force vector acted on p1 by p2
getForce :: Particle -> Particle -> Vec
getForce p1 p2
    | p1 == p2 = scalar 0.0
    | otherwise = scalar (g * (m1 * m2 / r^2)) * unit
    where
        m1 = mass p1
        m2 = mass p2
        r1 = position p1
        r2 = position p2
        dr = r2 - r1
        r = norm_2 dr
        unit = normalize dr

-- | Calculate the net gravitational force acted on the particle by
-- all the other particles
netForce :: Particle -> [Particle] -> Vec
netForce p ps = sum (map (getForce p) ps)


-- | Update the position and velocity of a particle in the system
-- through a given timestep
move :: Double -> System -> Particle -> Particle
move h sys p = let
    (pos, vel) = (position p, velocity p)
    acc        = (netForce p $ particles sys) / (scalar $ mass p)
    in
    p { position = pos + scalar h * vel
        , velocity = vel + scalar h * acc
        }

stepSize = 1000

-- | Update the system through one timestep
evolve :: System -> System
evolve sys = sys { particles = ps' }
    where
      ps' = map (move stepSize sys) (particles sys) `using` parList rdeepseq

-- | Stream of system at different timesteps
evolution :: System -> [System]
evolution = iterate evolve



sys1 :: System
sys1 = mkSystem
    [ (mkVector [1.496e11, 0], mkVector [0, 2.98e4], 5.974e24)
    , (mkVector [2.279e11, 0], mkVector [0, 2.41e4], 6.42e23)
    , (mkVector [5.79e10, 0], mkVector [0, 4.8e4], 3.3e23)
    , (mkVector [0, 0], mkVector [0, 0], 1.98e30)
    , (mkVector [ 1.08e11, 0], mkVector [0, 3.5e4], 4.87e24)
    ]


main :: IO ()
main = do
    [n] <- fmap (map read) getArgs :: IO [Int]
    let states = evolution sys1
        finalState = states !! n

    finalState `deepseq` (return ())
```

What is limiting the parallelism?

Comment: Without looking at the details too closely, you probably want `parListChunk` instead of `parList` - the computation you are parallelizing is so small that the overhead of sparking parallel evaluation for __each__ element is not worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Two thoughts:

1. I don't recommend HMatrix. It's a “Matlab in a box” library, which not only goes strongly against Haskell's grain in terms of semantics (dynamical dimension checking<sup>†</sup> etc.) but also subverts Haskell's better sides in performance. The idea of HMatrix/Matlab is to work with *large, monolithic, heap-allocated arrays* and do as much as possible with linear algebra primitives (which are implemented in C). This approach makes sense in a slow language like Matlab or Python (you delegate the inner loops to another, faster language), but not really in Haskell: the external calls can't properly be inlined, unlike native Haskell functions, and they add some overhead which though it may be negligible when crunching *large* vectors, can definitely add up for small ones. Pointer indirection harms cache performance.

   The most popular static, native LA library is [`linear`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear), which takes a much more Haskell-oriented approach (functors everywhere), and has proper tight memory layout. (I'm actually not such a fan of the interface itself, but the data types [can also be used](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-vector-spaces) with the very nice [`vector-space`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.14/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html) operators.)

   Switching to the types from `linear` improves the performance (single-threaded) by a factor 10 for me.

   ```
   import Data.VectorSpace
   import Data.VectorSpace.Free
   import Linear.V2

   import Data.List (zipWith4)
   import Data.List.Split
   import Control.DeepSeq
   import System.Environment
   import Control.Parallel.Strategies


   type Vec = V2 Double  -- In case you're wondering: you don't need to
                         -- hard-code the dimension, you can also make your
                         -- functions _polymorphic_ on the vector space.

   data Particle = Particle
       { tag      :: !Int
       , position :: !Vec
       , velocity :: !Vec
       , mass     :: !Double
       }

   instance Eq Particle where
     p1 == p2 = (tag p1) == (tag p2)

   instance Show Particle where
     show p = show $ position p

   instance NFData Particle where
     rnf p = t `seq` ps `seq` vel `seq` m `seq` ()
       where
           t   = tag p
           ps  = position p
           vel = velocity p
           m   = mass p

   data System = System
       { number :: Int
       , particles :: [Particle]
       }

   instance Show System where
       show sys = show (particles sys)

   instance NFData System where
       rnf sys = rnf $ particles sys


   g :: Double
   g = 6.674e-11

   -- | Construct a vector from a list of elements
   mkVector :: [Double] -> Vec
   mkVector [x,y] = V2 x y

   -- | Construct a system from a given list of
   -- position vectors, velocity vectors, and masses
   mkSystem :: [(Vec, Vec, Double)] -> System
   mkSystem xs = System
       { number = length xs
       , particles = map (apply Particle) $ zipWith cons [0..] xs
       }
       where
       cons y (a, b, c)     = (y, a, b, c)
       apply f (y, a, b, c) = f y a b c


   -- | Calculate the gravitational force vector acted on p1 by p2
   getForce :: Particle -> Particle -> Vec
   getForce p1 p2
       | p1 == p2   = zeroV
       | otherwise  = (g * (m1 * m2 / r^2)) *^ unit
       where
           m1 = mass p1
           m2 = mass p2
           r1 = position p1
           r2 = position p2
           dr = r2 - r1
           r = magnitude dr
           unit = dr ^/ r

   -- | Calculate the net gravitational force acted on the particle by
   -- all the other particles
   netForce :: Particle -> [Particle] -> Vec
   netForce p ps = sum (map (getForce p) ps)


   -- | Update the position and velocity of a particle in the system
   -- through a given timestep
   move :: Double -> System -> Particle -> Particle
   move h sys p = let
       (pos, vel) = (position p, velocity p)
       acc        = (netForce p $ particles sys) ^/ mass p
       in
       p { position = pos ^+^ h *^ vel
           , velocity = vel ^+^ h *^ acc
           }

   stepSize = 1000

   -- | Update the system through one timestep
   evolve :: System -> System
   evolve sys = sys { particles = ps' }
       where
         ps' = map (move stepSize sys) (particles sys) `using` parList rdeepseq

   -- | Stream of system at different timesteps
   evolution :: System -> [System]
   evolution = iterate evolve



   sys1 :: System
   sys1 = mkSystem
       [ (mkVector [1.496e11, 0], mkVector [0, 2.98e4], 5.974e24)
       , (mkVector [2.279e11, 0], mkVector [0, 2.41e4], 6.42e23)
       , (mkVector [5.79e10, 0], mkVector [0, 4.8e4], 3.3e23)
       , (mkVector [0, 0], mkVector [0, 0], 1.98e30)
       , (mkVector [ 1.08e11, 0], mkVector [0, 3.5e4], 4.87e24)
       ]


   main :: IO ()
   main = do
       [n] <- fmap (map read) getArgs :: IO [Int]
       let states = evolution sys1
           finalState = states !! n

       finalState `deepseq` (return ())
   ```
2. I wouldn't expect too gain much from parallelisation for only five particles anyhow. Each thread has very little it can do before giving back control, and everything interacts. You therefore quickly notice the overhead even of Haskell's light green threads.

   To benefit properly from parallelisation, you'll need to either set up the threads as a thread pool (like you would in traditional number-crunching languages) and thus avoid the sparking overhead, or make sure each thread has a lot to do. This works best if you mostly decouple the threads' domains; in really-many body applications this is done with something like a [Barnes-Hut simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes%E2%80%93Hut_simulation).

Another thing: you're right now using a simple Euler solver for solving the equations of motion. That's a very bad scheme. Switching to a higher-order [Runge Kutta solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods), ideally with adaptive step size, would allow you to save so much in terms of *number of steps* that the parallelisation aspect largely pales in impact by comparison.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Actually, HMatrix also has had [a statically checked module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix-0.19.0.0/docs/Numeric-LinearAlgebra-Static.html) for quite some time now.</sub>